# Tethering not working: Activation failed

Tags: 18.04, huawei, tethering

I am trying to connect to the internet on my mobile phone through tethering. I cannot seem to do this through any of the three methods: bluetooth, wifi hotspot, or usb.

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 and a Huawei Nova.

The phone shows that a device is connected when using bluetooth and wifi tethering but Ubuntu cannot seem to connect. I keep getting an `Activation failed` message.

I am using the same laptop that I used Ubuntu 16.04 on and tethering was working out of the box. The Ubuntu 16.04 was a regular install compared to this (minimal) installation. Might this have to do with the minimal installation? Some package might not be installed?

**Update**: Following [this post](https://computingforgeeks.com/install-and-configure-dnsmasq-on-ubuntu-18-04-lts/) I set the configuration file similarly except for the domain which I left commented. `dnsmasq` starts when I disable and stop `systemd-resolved` but the problem persists.

Comment: Do you have dnsmasq installed and configured? `dpkg -l dnsmasq`

Comment: No it was not installed. I installed it however it still fails to connect. Moreover, during booting of the system there's a `[Failed] Failed to start dnsmas`.

Comment: What kind of configuration?

Comment: `/etc/dnsmasq.conf`, and you can `man dnsmasq`.

Comment: Yes it is installed. The config file is the default. It is commented out. I will update my question with the lines I commented out and edited.

Comment: You should be running systemd-resolve, but you must do item #3 in my answer for dnsmasq and systemd-resolve to co-exist nicely.

Answer (score 0):

1. after installing dnsmasq, you need to configure it. Check /etc/dnsmasq.conf.
2. you can temporarily try setting a unused static IP/DNS addresses in the phone, and see if you can reach the Internet then.
3. if you're running both dnsmasq and systemd-resolved...

Do a `ps auxc | grep -i dns` and `ps auxc | grep -i resolv` and look for `dnsmasq` and `systemd-resolved`, and if both are running, you need to disable the DNS part of `systemd-resolved` by editing `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf` and...

change:

```
#DNSStubListener=yes
```

to:

```
DNSStubListener=no
```

Comment: This entry does not exist in the commented out content. Adding it to the end results in an error about it.

Comment: @user10853 what file are you editing?